# C++ boost thread id and Singleton

Tags: c++, boost, singleton, multithreading

Sorry to flood so many questions this week.

I assume thread index returned by `thread.get_id` is implementation specific.
In case of the pthreads, is index reused?  IE, if thread 0 runs and joins, is thread launched afterwords going to have a different ID?

the reason I ask this is a need to implement Singleton pattern with a twist:  each thread gets its own instance.  I know it sounds very crazy, but threads control hardware (cuda) which does not permit device memory sharing,  even at thread level.
What is a good way to implement such pattern?

Comment: Can't you use TLS for the singleton data?

Comment: @neil I do not know what what TLS is.  edit: nevermind, thread local storage

Comment: TLS == Thread Local Storage - memory that belongs to a specific thread

Comment: @neil yes, this is what I need.  I was not aware of how to use it. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a global (singleton) where each thread gets its own instance, use thread local storage. Boost has [thread_specific_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) for this.